# create a function to nest uiimageview over a uiview

Tags: swift, constraints, scale, func, cgrect

I am looking to create a extension function to nest and combine to objects into 1 object. I want the uiview on the bottom and the uiimageveiw on the top. So when the user calls the function it reacts to this combined object. Since both objects are at the exact same position it should work.

```
var grant = UIImageView()
var drawPlace = UIView()

viewdidload(){
NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
    drawPlace.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
    drawPlace.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -100),
    drawPlace.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
    drawPlace.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),

    grant.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
    grant.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -100),
    grant.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
    grant.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),

])}
```

Comment: What's the issue you're having? It's helpful if you describe what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn’t working?  I’ve answered 2 very similar questions for you already and you should be able to easily get a solution to this from one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58385199/4305676):

And my clarification answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424384/4305676):

(yes I know know an explanation is better, but this was a long response)
I'm only linking to my own posts because OP accepted both as answers, so I'm assuming he will use those extensions in his app.

If drawPlace and grant are subView of self.view, you take a screenshot of self.view at the location of drawPlace

Another option is to add grant as a subview of drawPlace and then take a screenshot of drawPlace with its own bounds.